# Vs2008 & Vs2010, starteam 2009, integrations broken

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, starteam

So I've been using VS2008 & vs2010 with the starteam 2009 integrations for a while.
in a recent updating frenzy, our IT departemnt required us to remove a bunch of "old java stuff" that
their scan tool said neede to be updated, but which java didn't update. Basically all the "for boreland" entrys.

Needless to say this killed starteam and it's integrations. Reinstalling starteam fixed it, but even after uninstalling vs2008, vs2010 starteam 9 and the integrations and reinstalling, I'm still getting this error when loading a project in etiher vs2008 or vs2010.

**The project .csproj appears to be under source control, but the associated source control plug-in is not installed on this computer. Source control will be disabled for this project.**

I also tried copying the java folder in borland from a working box... this fixed some folks, but not me.

Anyone know how to fix this so I can get my integrations working?

My best guess is there is some prerequsite that is not getting installed by the installers, 
either becuase it's improperly uninstalled, or I'm supposed to install it manually.
So if you know what the prerequsites are that'd be a big help.

Thanks,

Eric-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wound up reimaging the box to fix this issue, wasn't able to find the real fix.

Eric-